# Dumping variant array to range - VBA excel error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I'm using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) for Excel in order to save data into an array by:

```
Dim allPosts As Variant
allPosts = Range("A2:J5000")
```

after that I'm changing data in the `allPosts` array, and then I want to paste it back by:

```
Range("A2:J5000").Value = allPosts
```

I'm getting the error:

> run time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined

and the copy stops at a specific cell, when i **change the string at this cell to be shorter** the problem is solved.

thanks

Comment: Submit whatever you have. I don't know about the others but I have no crystal ball at hand.

Comment: the changes I'm performing on allPosts array are complicated, hence the built-in macro recorder didn't help

Comment: well, use recorder to see how paste function works; adapt it to your needs

Comment: the paste function works, only when it reach the very long string cell it crash. thanks!

Comment: Have you tried just looping over your array and pasting it to destination cells one at the time? `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353(v=office.11).aspx`

Comment: @Andrew, the macro recorder is useful for basic mimicking of manual actions - using variant arrays is a programming technique with no manual equivalent.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a second array to store the cell lengths that are too long, and separately iterate over these

From [this Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;818808&Product=xl2003&wa=wsignin1.0) [excel-2003](/questions/tagged/excel-2003) can't handle writing back array strings longer than **911** characters [excel-2010](/questions/tagged/excel-2010) worked fine on my testing)

The code below:

1. Sets up a major variant array that reads in the range
2. Sets up a second blank variant of equal size to the first array
3. Tests each part of the array for cell length of more than 911 characters and then either

   - manipulates the shorter value in the first array, or,
   - removes the value from the first array, and then writes it to the second array
4. The first array is dumped in a single shot back to the range
5. The second array is iterated cell by cell to dump back the other strings

**code**

```
    Sub KudosRickyPonting()
    Dim allPosts As Variant
    Dim allPosts2 As Variant
    Dim vStrs As Variant
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    allPosts = Range("A2:J5000").Value2
    ReDim allPosts2(1 To UBound(allPosts, 1), 1 To UBound(allPosts, 2))

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(allPosts, 1)
        For lngCol = 1 To UBound(allPosts, 2)
            If Len(allPosts(lngRow, lngCol)) < 912 Then
                allPosts(lngRow, lngCol) = "Updated:" & allPosts(lngRow, lngCol)
            Else
                allPosts2(lngRow, lngCol) = "NEW PART " & allPosts(lngRow, lngCol)
                'erase long value from first array
                allPosts(lngRow, lngCol) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Range("A2:J5000").Value = allPosts

    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(allPosts2, 1)
        For lngCol = 1 To UBound(allPosts2, 2)
            If Len(allPosts2(lngRow, lngCol)) > 0 Then Range("A2").Offset(lngRow - 1, lngCol - 1).Value2 = allPosts2(lngRow, lngCol)
        Next
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: thanks!!! is there a way to slice down strings that are longer than 911? This way I will run normally on allPosts, when a long string apear I will slice it down, and at last I will paste allPosts back to the Sheet normally by: Range("A2:J5000").Value = allPosts

Comment: Agree with Doug... Very Nice :)

Comment: Uped for KudosRickyPonting