# VBA - Summing Array column with conditions - Like excel sumif

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, multidimensional-array, while-loop

I would like to sum a *column* in an array based on several conditions.
If the data were in Excel I would use a `=SUMIFS` formula.

The sample dataset in a 2 dimensional array I have is:

```
ID1     ID2     ID3     Value
0       1       1       4
0       2       2       5
1       3       2       6
0       1       1       3
0       1       0       2
```

I would like to sum the value column based on the following conditions:

```
ID1=0
ID2=1
ID3=1
```

Therefore rows 1 and 4 meet this criteria and hence the answer would be 7 (4+3)

How Would I construct this in VBA.

Note that the ID's may be infinite and they may be strings either so I **can't** set `ID=0` in the loop.

Comment: Did you try nested For + Ifs?

Comment: show code how your array is constructed. Is it a VBA variant array or is the data on the spreadsheeet?

Comment: Well technically your ID's *can't* be infinite. There can be a lot, LOT of entries, but at one point you'll hit a stop sign.

Answer (score 5):

Just a small warning on the speed!

I believe the question is for a **2D array** and not for a **excel.range** because a loop on an excel range is very sloooooowly (valid only if you have a lot of data, but I bet that is the usual case if you plan to use a VBA macro ;-) )

I have suffer from the slowness of the range before until I found a few links reporting this issue (For an example with 10000 cells, one user reports 9,7seg vs. 0,16 seg using the 2D array!!). The links are below. My recommendation is to use always 2D array, **simple, clean and fast!**

See more performance tests in:

- http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/12/04/writing-to-a-range-using-vba/
- http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2008/10/03/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-scan-a-large-range-in-excel.aspx

Therefore, if you want to process a lot of data, the code of Jakub's reply should changed just a bit, in order the gain the *power* of the **2D array**:

```
Public Function sumIfMultipleConditionsMet2(rng As Range, ParamArray conditions() As Variant) As Double
    Dim conditionCount As Long: conditionCount = UBound(conditions) + 1
    Dim summedColumnIndex As Long: summedColumnIndex = conditionCount + 1
    Dim currentRow As Range
    Dim result As Double: result = 0 'Changed from Long to Double
    Dim i As Long

    If rng.Columns.Count <> conditionCount + 1 Then
        Err.Raise 17, , "Invalid range passed"
    End If        

    Dim conditionsMet As Boolean

    'USING AN ARRAY INSTEAD OF A RANGE
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = rng.Value 'Copy the range to an array
    Dim r As Long

    For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)  'OLD: For Each currentRow In rng.Rows
        conditionsMet = True
        For i = LBound(conditions) To UBound(conditions)
            ' cells collection is indexed from 1, the array from 0
            ' OLD: conditionsMet = conditionsMet And (currentRow.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = conditions(i))
            conditionsMet = conditionsMet And (arr(r, i + 1) = conditions(i))
        Next i

        If conditionsMet Then
            'OLD: result = result + currentRow.Cells(1, summedColumnIndex).Value
            result = result + arr(r, summedColumnIndex)
        End If
    Next r

    sumIfMultipleConditionsMet2 = result
End Function
```

Use it the same way that Jakub showed in his reply:

```
debug.Print sumIfMultipleConditionsMet2(Range("A1:D50000"), 0, 1, 1)
```

Hope you like it!

Regards,
Andres

---

PS: If you want to go further, here are more speed tips for excel. Hope you like it!

- http://www.avdf.com/apr98/art_ot003.html  //See tip#1 - good info on writing fast VBA code for Excel.
- http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices.aspx - fast coding
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153090/en-us - pass an Excel array to VB
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177991 - some limitations when passing arrays to sheets (excel 2000 a bit old!)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the paramArray feature to get a more generalized version of the sumif function. For example:

```
Public Function sumIfMultipleConditionsMet(rng As range, ParamArray conditions() As Variant) As Long
Dim conditionCount As Long: conditionCount = UBound(conditions) + 1
Dim summedColumnIndex As Long: summedColumnIndex = conditionCount + 1
Dim currentRow As range
Dim result As Long: result = 0
Dim i As Long

If rng.Columns.Count <> conditionCount + 1 Then
    Err.Raise 17, , "Invalid range passed"
End If


Dim conditionsMet As Boolean

For Each currentRow In rng.Rows
    conditionsMet = True

    For i = LBound(conditions) To UBound(conditions)
        ' cells collection is indexed from 1, the array from 0
        conditionsMet = conditionsMet And (currentRow.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = conditions(i))
    Next i

    If conditionsMet Then
        result = result + currentRow.Cells(1, summedColumnIndex).Value
    End If
Next

sumIfMultipleConditionsMet = result
End Function
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
debug.Print sumIfMultipleConditionsMet(Range("A1:D5"), 0, 1, 1)
```

Comment: further reading about the paramArray available [here](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1005%20ParamArray.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

OK, you said you have a 2D array (not an excel range), but the exact shape of the array was not specificated. So I have to assume your 2D array is call "arr" and has the form of: `arr(c,r) as variant` , where `r` is used for accessing the rows and `c` for the columns (1 for "ID1", 2 for "ID2", 3 for "ID3" and 4 for "Value"). *(See "note 1" and "note 2" for further clarification if you are not following the idea).*

Then you just have to make a small loop:

```
tot = 0
For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) ' The "2" in the second paramenter is
                                         ' for getting the lower and upper bound
                                         ' of the "2nd" dimention of the array
    If arr(1, i) = A And arr(2, i) = B And arr(3, i) = C Then
        tot = tot + arr(4, i)
    End If
Next i
```

The `tot` variable will have the total you was trying to calculate. Easy??

If you want to warp the previous in a function, you can use:

```
Public Function SumIfMyArray(arr As Variant, A As Variant, _
                             B As Variant, C As Variant) As Double
    Dim i as Long
    Dim tot As Double
    tot = 0
    For i = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2) 
        If arr(1, i) = A And arr(2, i) = B And arr(3, i) = C Then
            tot = tot + arr(4, i) 'Adding the filtered value
        End If
    Next i

    SumIfMyArray = tot 'Returning the calculated sum

End Function
```

Use it like: `Debug.Print SumIfMyArray(YouArr, 1, 1, 1)`. Hope this helps.

MORE COMPLEX (BUT FLEXIBLE):

Now, if you want to have a very generic function that support different criterias and at the same time to be flexible with the columns, you can use the code below (Note, I'm using the ParamArray like in other reply). Actually the function can use an array in the form `arr(c,r)` (that array form is easier to adding more rows with `redim` instruction) and the second in the form `arr(r,c)` (this array form is simpler if you copy an excel range using `arr=range("A1:D5")` ).

```
Private Function SumIfConditionsMetArray(ColToAdd As Long, Arr As Variant, _
                       TypeArrayIsRC As Boolean, _
                       ParamArray Criteria() As Variant) As Double
    ' Returns:     The sum of values from a column where
    '              the row match the criteria.
    ' Parameters:
    ' 1) Arr:      An array in the form of arr(row,col) (
    '              (like the array passed by an excel range)
    ' 2) ColToAdd: Index of column you want to add.
    ' 3) TypeArrayIsRC: 'True' if the array passed if in the
    '              form of arr(Row,Column) or 'False' if
    '              the array is in the form arr(Column,Row).
    '              Note that passing an range as
    '              arr=range("A1:B3").value , then "true"
    '              should be used!
    ' 4) Criteria: a list of criteria you want to use for
    '              filtering, if you want to skip a column
    '              from the criteria use "Null" in the
    '              parameter list.
    '
    ' Example: Debug.Print SumIfConditionsMetArray(4, data, true, 9, null, 5)
    '          (It means: sum column 4 of data where 1st column
    '                     match "9" and 3rd column match "5".
    '                     The 2nd column was skipped because of null)

    Dim tot As Double
    Dim CountCol As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    Dim conditionsMet As Boolean
    Dim cExtra As Long
    Dim DimRow As Long, DimCol As Long

    If TypeArrayIsRC Then
        DimRow = 1: DimCol = 2
    Else
        DimRow = 2: DimCol = 1
    End If

    'Some checking...
    If ColToAdd < LBound(Arr, DimCol) Or ColToAdd > UBound(Arr, DimCol) Then
        Err.Raise vbError + 9, , "Error in function SumIfConditionsMetArray. ColToAdd is out of the range."
    End If

    'Correction in case of different array bases..
    cExtra = LBound(Arr, DimCol) - LBound(Criteria)  'In case the lower bound were different...

    'Limit the last column to check
    CountCol = UBound(Criteria)
    If CountCol > UBound(Arr, DimCol) - cExtra Then
        'Not raising an error, just skip out the extra parameters!
        '(Put err.raise if you want an error instead)
        CountCol = UBound(Arr, DimCol) - cExtra
    End If

    On Error GoTo errInFunction

    '''' LOOP ''''
    Dim A As Long
    Dim B As Long
    tot = 0
    For r = LBound(Arr, DimRow) To UBound(Arr, DimRow)
        If TypeArrayIsRC Then
            A = r
        Else
            B = r
        End If
        conditionsMet = True
        For c = LBound(Criteria) To CountCol
            If Not IsNull(Criteria(c)) Then
                If TypeArrayIsRC Then
                    B = c + cExtra
                Else
                    A = c + cExtra
                End If
                If Arr(A, B) <> Criteria(c) Then
                    conditionsMet = False 'Creteria not met
                End If
            End If
        Next c
        If TypeArrayIsRC Then
            B = ColToAdd
        Else
            A = ColToAdd
        End If
        If conditionsMet Then
            tot = tot + Arr(A, B) 'Adding the value
        End If
    Next r

    SumIfConditionsMetArray = tot 'Returning the calculated sum
    Exit Function
    ''' END '''
errInFunction:
    Err.Raise Err.Number, , "Error in function SumIfConditionsMetArray. Check the parameters are inside the bounds."
End Function
```

Is a bit more tricky but much more flexible. You can use it with a range as:

```
Dim MyArr as variant
MyArr = ActiveSheet.range("A1:G10").Value  ' Note: use ".Value" at end  
                                           ' and not start with "Set" 
Debug.Print SumIfConditionsMetArray(4, MyArr, True, 100,  null, 100)
' This will add the value of the 4th column, were the row 
' has 100 in the first column and 100 in the 3rd column.
```

Hoping this help with your question.

Regards, Andres

---

** *Note 1* **  When having an array in the form of `arr(c,r)` you can access any element by giving the coordinates inside the parenthesis. For example, if you want to access the value of 4th column of the 2nd row, you have to code `arr(4,2)` and you will get the value of 5 (provided you are testing the same example of your question. Check it in your first table).

** *Note 2* ** I have a reason for the `arr(c,r)` instead of `arr(r,c)`. The reason is because it is much more easier if you want to add more rows with the `redim` instruction if you have the row coordinate in a the last position. But if you 2D array is coming from a excel range (Using for example something like `arr = range("A3:D6").value`), then it will be better to flip the r and c position in the code.

Comment: +1 for your solution and clear explanation. I like Jakub's solution a little better but still even if it was an excel range you could [easily stick it in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481330/2-dimensional-array-vba-from-cell-contents-in-excel/18481730#18481730).

Comment: Thank you! and I agree you can easy copy a range to an 2D Array (That is what I show the last block of code!) Just a warning: if you iterate excel cell by excel cell is veerrrryyy slooowwwwly. You have to iterate (make a loop) in the 2D array only. Not kidding, try a 5 col x 1000 rows. Reading range("A1:E1000").cell(x,y) is 100 times slower than to copy one time to an 2D Array and iterate through it.