# Pass range into an array and retrieve value

Tags: arrays, vba

I seem to have a fairly simple problem which is giving me grief. The following code throws a 'Subscript out of range' error. Therefore, I assume that the array is not being populated? Can anyone spot the glaring hole in what am I doing wrong...?

```
Dim p() As Variant
p = Sheet4.Range("G20:G29")

Sheet4.Select
Range("R2") = p(0)
```

ps G20:G29 contain strings, no blank cells

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 Dimensional array from range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481330/2-dimensional-array-from-range)

Answer (score 3):

Hold it. Figured out the syntax. Forgot the Variant array was multidimensional

```
'First item
Range("R2") = p(1, 1)

'Second item
Range("R2") = p(2, 1)
```

Comment: +1 for solving on your own. Also the base of a range array is 1 instead of the typical 0.  Use the `Locals` window in Excel to see the structure of your arrays :)  Alternatively you could do `Range("R2") = Application.Transpose(p)(1)`

Comment: @David. Thanks for the reply. Was wondering if you knew the reason why the base was 1, not 0 in a multi dimensional array. Seems to juxtapose tradition.

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays are not always Base 1. Range arrays are always base 1, whether they are single- or multi-dimensional. I am not sure off the top of my head but probably has something to do with a Range being an indexed collection of cells.  Collections don't have an item `0`, so it would make sense to force the same logic on a range array.

Comment: Cheers Dave, makes sense :)