# Declare a Range relative to the Active Cell with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to declare a range object relative to the Active Cell.  The problem is, the number of rows and columns I want to select is different each time the macro runs.

For example, I have two variables: `numRows` and `numCols`.

I want to select a range that has the ActiveCell in the upper-left corner hand has the cell with row ActiveCell.Row + NumRows and column ActiveCell.Column + NumCols in the bottom right (and then I intend to copy this data to an array to speed up my macro).

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an [**.Offset** property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060(v=office.15).aspx) on a Range class which allows you to do just what you need

`ActiveCell.Offset(numRows, numCols)`

follow up on a comment:

```
Dim newRange as Range
Set newRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(numRows, numCols))
```

and you can verify by `MsgBox newRange.Address`

and [here's how to assign this range to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481330/2-dimensional-array-from-range/18481730#18481730)

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ActiveCell.Resize(numRows, numCols)
```

then read the contents of that range to an array:

```
Dim arr As Variant
arr = rng.Value
'arr is now a two-dimensional array of size (numRows, numCols)
```

or, select the range (I don't think that's what you really want, but you ask for this in the question).

```
rng.Select
```

Comment: ++ I like the alternative and I believe it's a better way to achieve what the OP asks for in this scenario.