# loop through a range but use the nxt col as value

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel code that looks at range A1:A100...it loops through those ranges, but when it loops, I wanted to pick the value in col B...for instance, when the range loop starts, it'll look at A1 first, but in the VBA, I want it to pick the value in B1 to use...

```
Sub DRAWb()
'
' DRAWb Macro
'

'
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A3")

For Each cell In rng


If cell.Value > 1 Then


    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 11.25, 50 * cell, 93.75, 43.5) _
        .Name = "R cell"
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: try: `cell.Offset(0,1)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declare a Range relative to the Active Cell with VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409175/declare-a-range-relative-to-the-active-cell-with-vba)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `.Offset` method, which "Returns a Range object that represents a range that’s offset from the specified range."

```
If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value > 1 Then
```

The above would evaluate to the *next* column.

Documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060%28v=office.15%29.aspx