# Excel VBA Run-time Error '6' when populating an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have resolved this issue.  The problem was nothing (directly) to do with the code.  It was to do with the lRow variable.  This value was populated by a formula on my spreadsheet and this was in turn populated by another macro.  I discovered that I had inserted a column and was consequently updating the wrong column.  I changed my code to update a named range rather than an actual address and the problem disappeared.  Still a bit odd that this code was failing as the values in row 24 appear valid to me.

Thanks for all the input!

---

Hope someone can help here.  I have recently started to get an error when trying to run my code.

[image: Run-time error '6']

This error arises at this line of code:

```
NewArr = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("A" & lRow & ":BJ" & lRow).Value
```

The variable is declared above as:

```
Dim NewArr() As Variant
```

lRow is evaluating as 24 so the idea is that the array called NewArr will be populated with the values that appear on Input Sheet range A24:BJ24.

I know that the variant data type can handle very large numbers and although there are some big numbers and text etc in this row, none are over 4 million.  (One is 3380438.98545603).  Any ideas as to why I am getting this error?

TIA!

My full code (up to the point where I get the error) is:

```
Private Sub BT_SUBMIT_Click()

Dim NewArr As Variant
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim PasteRange As Range
Dim bUpdated As Boolean

'Check if the user  has ticked the confirm box before writing to the spreadsheet
If Me.XB_CONFIRM.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "You must tick the confirm box to indicate you understand that " _
    & "your amendments cannot be undone.  Please return to the form, tick the box and " _
    & "resubmit.", vbOKOnly, "Please tick confirmation box"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check if the user has selected either yes or no on changes frame
If Me.OB_CHNGS_NO.Value = False And Me.OB_CHNGS_YES.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "You must select either yes or no to indicate if there are changes being made." _
    & "  Please correct and resubmit.", vbCritical, "Select Yes or No"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Check if the Target Resolution Date is at least today or later and if not
'user must update
If Sheets("Input Sheet").Cells(Sheets("Lookups").Range("NEW_IAR_ROW").Value, 38).Value < Now() And Me.OB_CHNGS_YES.Value = False Then

    MsgBox "The Target Resolution Date must be no earlier than today." _
    & "  Please correct and resubmit.", vbCritical, "Change Target Resolution Date"

    Me.OB_CHNGS_YES.Value = True
    Exit Sub
End If


'Check if the values enterered are valid
If Me.OB_CHNGS_YES Then
    If Control_Error("FR_AMNDMENTS") Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If (Len(Me.TB_AMNT_RES.Value) + Len(Me.TB_NO_TRNS_RES.Value) + Len(Me.TB_CMNT_RES.Value)) > 0 Then
        bUpdated = True
        If Control_Error("FR_IAR_RSVD") Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    If (Len(Me.TB_AMNT_WO.Value) + Len(Me.TB_NO_TRNS_WO.Value) + Len(Me.TB_CMNT_WO.Value)) Then
        bUpdated = True
        If Control_Error("FR_IAR_WO") Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If (Len(Me.TB_AMNT_INC.Value) + Len(Me.TB_NO_TRNS_INC.Value) + Len(Me.TB_CMNT_INC.Value)) Then
        bUpdated = True
        If Control_Error("FR_IAR_INCR") Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    If Not (bUpdated) Then
        MsgBox "You have not entered any changes for resolved, write offs or increases.  " _
        & "You must update at least one of these sections or select no changes.", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

lRow = Sheets("Lookups").Range("NEW_IAR_ROW").Value
lCol = Sheets("Lookups").Range("TOTAL_COLUMNS").Value

'First we load the array with the current values on the sheet.
NewArr = Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("A" & lRow & ":BJ" & lRow).Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Then there is other code beyond this point
End Sub
```

Comment: can you show the line directly in front and after the `newArr=` line cus theoretically can't that error occur at that part of line...

Comment: It's not actually the size of the number that's the issue, it's the amount of bits that the number uses to store in memory. That being said the number you've quoted only uses 22 bits of memory so shouldn't be an issue really.

Comment: Have you tried to declare the varable as ```Dim NewArr As Variant```? Not array.

Comment: You could try to dimension the array to the size needed to load the range and then loop through the range, copying the data to the array element by element. That way you might be able to tell where the problem lies (assuming that the problem is actually in that line and not, as Dirk suggested, on a neighboring line).

Comment: I tried multiple ways of recreating your issue but cannot even with large random numbers. You may need to post some actual data. SO strongly recommends a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for all the replies.  I have added more of my code above.  Dee - I tried your suggestion but this made no difference.  John, I will take a look at your suggestion - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have enough rep to make a comment, I decide to write this as an answer.

I faced the same issue as you did and found two solutions.

I tried this answer of a related post ([Excel VBA load range into array overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26146939/excel-vba-load-range-into-array-overflow-error)) and it worked.
The catch is that I have a previous (functional) version of the project, so when I copied and pasted the code I used the code from the functioning (previous) version.

Alternatively, you can try and use .Value2 instead of .Value.
That was the other thing that did the trick with the added benefit of not having to create a new module to copy/paste the code (or have any version control of the project).

I hope that helps whoever may stumble on this issue