# Creating an array in VBA from spreadsheet data

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet of data that I want to put into a VBA array which then outputs unique values to a new sheet. I have got that to work so far. However, some of the cells in the original data have text separated by commas, and I want to add those to the array as well. I can't quite get that bit to work.

After the various 'dims', my code is

```
'Grabs the data to work with
Set rTable = Worksheets("Data Entry").Range("N1:N100", "P1:P100")
'Puts it into an array
MyArray = rTable.Value

'Sets where the data will end up
Set rCell = Worksheets("TestSheet").Range("A1:A100")


'Each unique entry gets added to the new array
On Error Resume Next
For Each a In MyArray
UnqArray.Add a, a
Next

'Add unique data to new location
For i = 1 To UnqArray.Count
rCell(i, 1) = UnqArray(i)
Next
```

I have tried doing a new variant to store the split data

```
SpArray = split(MyArray,", ")
```

and then have that here

```
MyArray = rTable.Value
SpArray = split(MyArray,", ")
```

and then refer to `SpArray` for the rest of the code

I've also tried to have as part of

```
For Each a in SpArray
```

but it doesn't work for me.

Do I need to do a separate loop on each cell of the array before I filter out the unique ones?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps.

Comment: see if [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18481730/2140173) helps

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful to read over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need another loop. But if you set a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and use a Dictionary object, you can eliminate the loop that writes to the range because Dictionary.Keys returns an array.

In this example, it attempts to split every entry on a comma and treats each of those as a unique. If there is no comma, Split returns the one value so it works in both cases. There's probably a small cost to splitting things that don't need to be split, but you won't notice until your range is much larger. And it makes the code cleaner, I think.

```
Sub WriteUniques()

    Dim dcUnique As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim vaSplit As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    vaData = Sheet1.Range("$I$12:$I$62").Value
    Set dcUnique = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = LBound(vaData, 1) To UBound(vaData, 1)
        vaSplit = Split(vaData(i, 1), ",")
        For j = LBound(vaSplit) To UBound(vaSplit)
            If Not dcUnique.Exists(vaSplit(j)) Then
                dcUnique.Add vaSplit(j), vaSplit(j)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheet1.Range("J12").Resize(dcUnique.Count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dcUnique.Keys)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get that to work as I wasn't abel to reference MSRuntime. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

The code tweak that worked for me was to put the Split at the end.

```
'Add unique data to new location
For i = 1 To UnqArray.Count
rCell(i, 1) = Split(UnqArray(i), ",")

Next
```

This then built up an array using data from different ranges and splitting up comma separated ones before outputting only the unique ones.