# Create dynamic VBA variable name

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, variant

I got a problem from my work.

I have to read data from a sheet and save it to lists.
I thought about a loop, because it have to be dynamic lists, because I don't want to lose the data in the next loop.

Firstly, I count the number of Sheet's column, and secondly, the rows of the indexer column.
For example:
for i=1 to maxHorizont 'horizontal
for j =1 to maxVertic 'vertical

readColumn would be the fix part of the name and I want to add the 'i' (indexer) to it.

The result would be this:
DIM readColumn1 as Object,
DIM readColumn2 as Object,
DIM readColumn3 as Object,
.
.
.

Could you have an ide to fix my problem?

Comment: You can't define variable names on the fly like that (just not something vba supports).

Comment: Use an array instead.

Comment: At any point of time you think that you have to declare multiple variables that serve the similar purpose and need to refer them by index - Think array (or collection).

Comment: Some helpful links: [Create an array from range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba), [2-dim array from range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481330/2-dimensional-array-from-range/18481730#18481730),
[Slice an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175170/how-do-i-slice-an-array-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Use either [Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/collection-object) or Array

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be using arrays.

Supossing you want to get Double values, your array should be declared like that:

```
ReDim readColumn1(0 To maxVertic) As Double
```

them you can pass it through a loop:

```
For i = 0 To maxVertic
     readColumn1(i) = worksheets("your_sheet").cells(i, your_column)
Next i
```

Using that logic, create one array for each column.