# Application defined error when handling cells with very long strings?

Tags: excel, vba

My working code has the line,

```
Cells(i - 1, 13) = Cells(i, 1)
```

Where `Cells(i - 1,13)` is blank, and `Cells(i,1)` contains text. The macro works fine, but when `cells(i,1)` has a very large amount of text, it throws up a Runtime error.

Is there a workaround for this? I know the problem is caused by the string being too long, as making it shorter avoids the error. It also works fine if I copy and paste the contents of the cell, rather than 'equalling' them. Googling gave me little information on this. Has anyone come across this limitation before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while copying more than 8202 characters from one cell to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085656/error-while-copying-more-than-8202-characters-from-one-cell-to-another)

Comment: `making it shorter avoids the error. It also works fine if I copy and paste the contents of the cell, rather than 'equalling' them.` so what is your question then?

Comment: I mean, I don't want to make the string shorter. I need the script to work on it as is. I mentioned this just to demonstrate that the length of the string was causing the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this: `Cells(i - 1, 13).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value`